# Configure dnf to use DNS-over-HTTPS (DoH) without using systemd-resolved

Tags: fedora, dns, dnf, https

Is there a way to configure dnf to use DNS-over-HTTPS (DoH) without using systemd-resolved or a proxy (i.e. dnscrypt-proxy)? I dont like have local servers running on desktops (even on loop back addresses).